# Jenkins Customize Editable Email Content

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, shellexecute

In my Jenkins step I have windows batch command which runs a java jar file (**java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\Test1\Test.jar C:\Test\test.log**) and output of which is a String value (verified Jenkins console the string is getting printed) . How will I use this string content and insert in the editable email content body so I can send this content as an email . I wouldn't want the whole Jenkins console in the email only this String. I would assume the string has to be set as an environment variable after the script runs . Not sure how exactly I can use EnvInjPlugin for my scenario if at all it can be.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have not enough reputation to *comment* Alex' great answer, so I write a new answer. The call

> `msg.setContent(contentToSet, "text/plain")`

has two disadvantages:

- Special characters are garbled
- An attachment gets lost

So I use the following call to set the modified text

> `((javax.mail.Multipart)msg.getContent()).getBodyPart(0).setContent(contentToSet, "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pre-send script.

For example You have in log the string like: "***this random integer should be in email content: 3432805***"
and want to add randomly generated integer to email content.

1. Set the **Default Content** with whatever you want but add some
   value which will be replaced. For example:

   ***This is the random int from build.log: TO_REPLACE***
2. Then click "Advanced Settings" and add **Pre-send Script**:

   ```
   String addThisStringToContent = "";
   build.getLog(1000).each() { line ->
         java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("random\\sinteger.+\\:\\s(\\d+)");
         java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
         if (m.find()) {
               addThisStringToContent = m.group(1);
         }
   }

   if (addThisStringToContent == "") {
         logger.println("Proper string not found. Email content has not been updated.");
   } else {
         String contentToSet = ((javax.mail.Multipart)msg.getContent()).getBodyPart(0).getContent().toString().replace("TO_REPLACE", addThisStringToContent);
         msg.setContent(contentToSet, "text/plain");
   }
   ```

where:

- `build.getLog(1000)` - retrieves the last 1000 lines of build output.
- `Pattern.compile("random\\sinteger.+\\:\\s(\\d+)")` - regex to find the proper string
- `"text/plain"` - Content Type
- `String contentToSet = ((javax.mail.Multipart)msg.getContent()).getBodyPart(0).getContent().toString().replace("TO_REPLACE", addThisStringToContent);` - replaces the string *TO_REPLACE* with your value

Hope it will help you.